# EclipseLink + PostgreSQL: UUID stopped to work after the upgrade to 4.0.0

Tags: postgresql, jpa, eclipselink, uuid

I'm using the UUID as a primary key in my solution and it worked perfectly on the older EclipseLink version 2.7.3, however, when I tried to upgrade to 4.0.0 I started getting an error during the invocation of the *find* method.

PK is defined as:

```
@Id
@Column(name="ID", columnDefinition="UUID")
@Convert(converter = UuidConverter.class)
protected UUID id;
```

Converter:

```
@Converter(autoApply = true)
public class UuidConverter implements AttributeConverter<UUID, UUID> {

    @Override
    public UUID convertToDatabaseColumn(UUID attribute) {
        return attribute;
    }

    @Override
    public UUID convertToEntityAttribute(UUID dbData) {
        return dbData;
    }
}
```

PostgreSQL trick to bypass the cast issue (please see https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/t/1073632/
for the details):

```
create or replace function uuid(_text character varying) returns uuid language sql as 'select uuid_in(_text::cstring)';
create cast (character varying as uuid) with function uuid(character varying) as assignment;
```

Find method:

```
public T find(Object id) {
    return getEntityManager().find(entityClass, id);
}
```

Error:

```
Internal Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: operator does not exist: uuid = character varying
Hint: No operator matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
Position: 96
```

So, the cast issue has returned despite that both the function and the cast were defined as listed above.

Entities are being stored in the DB fine, the problem appears only when I try to fetch them.

Comment: As a WA I switched to the 3.0.3 version and it worked fine. I submitted an issue https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/1805

Comment: Is it because the converter isn't being used? EL 4.0 uses Jakarta packages I believe, has your converter been updated as well, and is it being found by the persistence unit when it is processing your entity? (El logging on ALL or FINEST should show what it finds during deployment)

Comment: I didn't update the converter, and I'm not sure is it necessary to update it as long as AttributeConverter class wasn't deprecated. And as I understood from a similar issue converter is not needed for the 4.0.0 version anymore: https://github.com/eclipse-ee4j/eclipselink/issues/1771 However even without the converter it didn't work.

There was some fix under that issue but considering the changeset, I'm not sure that it will work. Need to check. I stick to the 3.0.3 version so far.

Comment: It needs to be changed from using javax to jakarta packages or it can't be picked up by the persistence unit.  The issue you linked was just fixed; you won't see it unless you use a nightly build.